# WordPress WooCommerce Custom Search with Category Input Issue

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, search, woocommerce

I'm building a custom WooCommerce (product) search form in addition to my default blog posts search function. I will display both search forms on the same page. The search form should also allow a search in a predefined product category which is selected by a dropdown. Unfortunately the search in the category after setting it in the dropdown always returns no results. Regardless if a search phrase is entered or not. If there is no search phrase entered it should at least display the products of the selected category. Any idea how to solve my problem or any better way to achieve my goal?

**1.** I put the following code into my functions.php to return the category-dropdown for my custom post-type (product)

```
    function test_dropdown_product_categories($show_option_none, $name, $selected = '') {
        return apply_filters('test_dropdown_product_categories', wp_dropdown_categories(array('hierarchical' => true, 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'show_option_none' => $show_option_none, 'exclude' => '1', 'hide_empty' => 0, 'name' => $name, 'orderby' => 'name', 'selected' => $selected, 'echo' => 0, 'class' => 'form-control')));  
    }
```

**2.** To separate the two html search forms I used different ids (s1 and s2) and values (1 and 2). Both forms working fine. The following is the form for the custom post type product

```
    <form method="get" id="s2" action="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>" class="form-inline">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" type="search" name="s" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Enter search phrase...', 'test'); ?>" />
            <?php
                echo test_dropdown_product_categories(__('All categories', 'test'), 'category', intval(isset($_GET['category'])));
            ?>          
            <input type="hidden" id="s2" name="filter" value="2" />
        <button class="button btn-test" type="submit"><?php _e('Start Searching', 'test'); ?></button>
    </form>
```

**3.** Then I created two custom search.php files called "search-posts.php" and "search-products.php"

**4.** To use the right custom search file I put the following into the search.php file

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['filter'])) {
            $type = $_GET['filter'];
                if($type == '1') {
                load_template( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/search-posts.php');
            } elseif($type == '2') {
                load_template( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/search-products.php');
            }
        }
    ?>
```

**5.** Then I used the following code to filter the search in search-products.php

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['filter']) && $_GET['filter'] == '2') {
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        
        if (isset($_GET['category']) && $_GET['category'] != '-1') {
            $args_category = array(
                'category__in' => intval($_GET['category'])
            );
        } else {
            $args_category = array();
        }       
        
        $orderby = ''; // To remove Notice ERROR when "WP-DEBUG" is "true"
        $args = array(
            's' => get_search_query(),
            'orderby' => $orderby,
            'order' => $order,
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'meta_key' => $meta_key,
            'paged' => $paged
        );

        $args = array_merge($args_category, $args);
                    
        query_posts($args);                     
    }

    get_template_part('index', 'test');
?>
```

**6.** Following URLs are generated after my search in a product category - but without any result

```
    mysite.com/online-shop/?s=&category=23&filter=2
    mysite.com/online-shop/?s=test&category=23&filter=2
```

**For the visual experience :)**

[image]
**Please do not suggest a plugin - I'm not interested in bloat. Thank you so much for your help.**